# Can one search action advance multiple search parties?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

Question in spoiler tags

> The search action requires you to discard a card to advance the search party one or more spaces. From September at least, it's possible to have one city which matches the requirements for two searches: a rioting Faded city (immunologist) with a military base (paranoid soldier). If I perform a search action in such a city, can I advance both tracks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

> The rules state *(emphasis mine)*:"Discard one or more cards to advance ***one*** search party token along a search track."